# why there are differences in web3 when using truffle and when used in the browser?

Tags: web3js, truffle

1- why listening to events in truffle require another library called truffle-assertions, why can't we just use `contractInstance.events.EventName()` like we do in the browser?

if truffle also use web3 then why can't we have that?

2- why calling functions is also different for example:

- calling a function that will create a transaction in the browser is like this:

  `functionName(param1, param2).send({parameters})`
- whilst in truffle we dont need to use send(),and we can specify the transaction parameter as a final arugment to functionName like this :

  `functionName(param1,param2,{from:accounts[0]})`
- calling a pure or view function in the browser:

  `functionName(param1,....,paramN).call()`
- in truffle :
  `functionName(para1..paramN)` // we dont use `.call()`

the previous functions will give the same results

Answer (score 0):

In short, truffle does some abstraction where it abstracts the complexity needed to interact with contracts and provides simple ways to call contracts, check logs, etc.

You can check more information here: https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts/#introducing-abstractions